# How to strip characters (in this case dashes "-") from YAML arrays using yq

Tags: arrays, bash, yaml, yq

Say I have a YAML array and I want to read the items into a bash array:

```
yaml='- this - is - a - yaml - array'
declare -a arr;
readarray -t arr < <(echo "$yaml" | yq -r '.');
echo ${arr[@]}
```

The bash array entries retain the `-` symbols.

**How might I strip out the `-` symbols using yq?**

---

Using [Mike Farrah's yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) (v4.31.2) but interested in answers for [Andrey Kislyuk's](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#) too.

Comment: You don't just strip `-`s, because you first have to identify which `-` are actually part of the array syntax, rather than parts of strings. Using a YAML parser like `yq`is the only sensible solution.

Comment: Re *The bash array entries retain the `-` symbols*: Of course they do, they are part of their value. Your (YAML-encoded) input string starts out with a dash, thus it constitutes an array item. But the rest of the (single line) string is just the value of that (one!) item itself, regardless of more dashes being part of it or not. These do not initiate more items (for that you'd need line breaks). So, you are dealing with an array that has exactly one item. To substitute (any) substrings in that item's value, you can use `sub` (and `gsub`).

Comment: @pmf thanks, a misunderstanding on my part. Note to self: **line breaks are required**. In my code,  I set the `yaml` variable via another yq command,  which seems to result in line breaks being removed.

Comment: [Quote](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/string-operators#string-blocks-bash-and-newlines) _"Bash is notorious for chomping on precious trailing newline characters..."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yaml='- this - is - a - yaml - array'
```

I suspect this isn't what you think it is in yaml. This is an array with a *single* element string with the value "this - is - a - yaml - array".

You need newline characters between each element.

The "-" is being printed because `yq` is printing the array yaml node rather than the child elements individually. You just need to splat the results:

```bash
echo "- this\n- is\n- a\n- yaml\n- array" | yq '.[]'

this
is
a
yaml
array
```

disclaimer: I wrote yq

Answer (score 0):

I did it by appending a bash [`tr`](https://ss64.com/bash/tr.html) command:

```
readarray -t arr < <(echo "$yaml" | yq -r '.' | tr -d '-');
```

I later figured out how to do it with `yq`'s [`sub`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/string-operators#sub-regex-replacement) function:

```
echo "$yaml" | yq '.[] | sub("-","")'
```

I think there should be a way with [`trim`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/string-operators#trim-strings) too, but I couldn't get anything working.